# Pyplot: add specific additional ticks and labels on right side with same scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add ticks and Labels on the right side for the values in the list "all_values". I don't want to add those values on the left becaue then it would overlap my Basic ticks on the yaxis. How can I add those values.
Here is the code from my plot (I changed the code according to the comment from below shorter and completely english):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

materials = {'42CrMo4 nitrocarburiert DNV': {'N_stat': 1e5, 'N_1': 1e5, 'N_D': 2e6, 'S_stat': 1240, 'S_1': 1240, 'S_D': 1030}}       

N_stat_values = []
S_stat_values = []
S_D_values = []

for material in materials:
    N = [1, materials[material]['N_stat'], materials[material]['N_1'], materials[material]['N_D'], 1e10]
    stress = [materials[material]['S_stat'], materials[material]['S_stat'], materials[material]['S_1'], materials[material]['S_D'], materials[material]['S_D']]
    N_stat_values.append(materials[material]['N_stat'])
    S_stat_values.append(materials[material]['S_stat'])
    S_D_values.append(materials[material]['S_D'])    
    plt.loglog(N, stress)

all_values = list(set(S_stat_values + S_D_values))

ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
plt.yticks(np.arange(1000, 1400, 100))
plt.grid(True, which='major',linewidth=0.5)
plt.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.3)
plt.xlim(np.min(N_stat_values)/10, 1e10)
```

gives the following figure:
[first try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfy9O.png)

Now I want to add ticks and Labels on the right side from the list all_values.
I tried to follow the hint from ImportanceOfBeingErnest:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

materials = {'42CrMo4 nitrocarburiert DNV': {'N_stat': 1e5, 'N_1': 1e5, 'N_D': 2e6, 'S_stat': 1240, 'S_1': 1240, 'S_D': 1030}}       

N_stat_values = []
S_stat_values = []
S_D_values = []

for material in materials:
    N = [1, materials[material]['N_stat'], materials[material]['N_1'], materials[material]['N_D'], 1e10]
    stress = [materials[material]['S_stat'], materials[material]['S_stat'], materials[material]['S_1'], materials[material]['S_D'], materials[material]['S_D']]
    N_stat_values.append(materials[material]['N_stat'])
    S_stat_values.append(materials[material]['S_stat'])
    S_D_values.append(materials[material]['S_D'])    
    plt.loglog(N, stress)

all_values = list(set(S_stat_values + S_D_values))

ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(1000, 1400, 100))
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax2.set_yticks(all_values)

plt.grid(True, which='major',linewidth=0.5)
plt.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.3)
plt.xlim(np.min(N_stat_values)/10, 1e10)
```

but I don't get the desired result, ticks on the right side are at wrong Location and minor ticks on x axis are gone:
[Next try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc5Om.png)

Comment: Your question is relevant. However, you could do some work in converting your question into something more minimal. Try to select the minimal ingredients and use generic (variable)names in English. Also you could include a figure with a current result.

Comment: Matplotlib does not allow to tick the left and right axis of an axes differently. The usual solution is hence to create a new axes (`ax2 = ax.twinx()`) and set the ticks and labels to this new axes. You will still need to set the limits of the new y axis yourself.

Comment: By "set the limits" I meant something like `ax2.set_ylim(ylimits)` where `ylimits` are the same for ax and ax2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest comment I was able to get my desired output:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

materials = {'42CrMo4 nitrocarburiert DNV': {'N_stat': 1e5, 'N_1': 1e5, 'N_D': 2e6, 'S_stat': 1240, 'S_1': 1240, 'S_D': 1030}}       

N_stat_werte = []
S_stat_werte = []
S_D_werte = []

for material in materials:
    N = [1, materials[material]['N_stat'], materials[material]['N_1'], materials[material]['N_D'], 1e10]
    stress = [materials[material]['S_stat'], materials[material]['S_stat'], materials[material]['S_1'], materials[material]['S_D'], materials[material]['S_D']]
    N_stat_values.append(materials[material]['N_stat'])
    S_stat_values.append(materials[material]['S_stat'])
    S_D_values.append(materials[material]['S_D'])    
    plt.loglog(N, stress)

all_values = list(set(S_stat_values + S_D_values))

ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_ylim(1000, 1300)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(1000, 1400, 100))
ax.grid(True, which='major',linewidth=0.5)
ax.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.3)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax2.set_yticks(all_values)
ax2.set_ylim(1000, 1300)
ax2.grid(True, which='major',linewidth=0.5)
plt.xlim(np.min(N_stat_values)/10, 1e10)
plt.show()
```

it Looks like this:
[image: final result]